How to prevent javax.xml.transform.Transformer from replacing non-BMP Unicode characters with numeric character references in UTF-8 encoding?
Background
I want to write an XML file containing non-BMP characters with UTF-8 encoding.
Problem
With the following code, the generated XML file replaces non-BMP Unicode characters with numeric character references.
package xml;

import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

public class XMLClass {

    static String names[] = {"一郎", "野","辻","‍‍"};

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = null;
        try {
            documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Document document = documentBuilder.newDocument();
        document.setXmlStandalone(true);

        Element list = document.createElement("list");
        document.appendChild(list);
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            Element name = (Element) document.createElement("name").cloneNode(false);
            list.appendChild(name);
            name.appendChild(document.createTextNode(names[i]));
        }

        File file = new File("NameList.xml");
        write(file, document);
    }


    public static boolean write(File file, Document document) {

        Transformer transformer = null;
        try {
             TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
             transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             return false;
        }

        transformer.setOutputProperty("indent", "yes");
        // non-BMP characters written in characters (no numeric character reference style)
        // when you set encoding UTF-16
        transformer.setOutputProperty("encoding", "UTF-8");
        transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xalan}indent-amount", "2");

        try {
             transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(
                       file));
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             return false;
        }

        return true;
   }
}

What I expected is:
<?xmlversion="1.0"encoding="UTF-8"?><list>
<name>一郎</name>
<name>野</name>
<name>辻</name>
<name>‍‍</name>
</list>

But what I got is:
<?xmlversion="1.0"encoding="UTF-8"?><list>
<name>&#131083;一郎</name>
<name>&#134071;野</name>
<name>辻&#917760;</name>
<name>&#128104;‍&#128105;‍&#128102;</name>
</list>

Question
How can I prevent javax.xml.transform.Transformer from replacing non-BMP Unicode characters with numeric character references when I specify to use UTF-8 encoding?

You QUESTION does not make sense.  The transform is replacing UNICODE character and your question says "non-BMP Unicode".  UTF-8 is one byte and unicode is two bytes.  The oriental characters are two bytes.  Some encoding will use one character for some oriental characters (0x80 to 0xFF) but there is only 128 characters that can be encoded.  It looks like you are sending the message as HTTP and some HTTP methods will escape characters (starting with &#).  It looks like the characters are being escaped.

The question makes perfect sense. There is no such thing as UNICODE. There are various representations of Unicode. UTF-8 and UTF-16 can represent all Unicode characters, including those outside of the BMP. The OP wants to prevent the transformer from using &-escapes for the non-BMP characters.

I don't know why Xalan is doing this, or whether it is something you can change, but you do of course have the option of switching to Saxon

Based on @Michael Kay's comment, switching the XSLT processor from Xalan to Saxon solves this problem. You have to add saxon-he-12.5.jar and xmlresolver-5.2.2.jar from Saxon-HE 12.5 to the classpath, and set the system property with -Djavax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl. This solution has the advantage of requiring no changes to the source code.

This is not a pretty solution, but… you can write to a pipe instead of a file, then read that pipe in a different thread and fix the numeric entities yourself, and send that fixed version to a file:
private static void writeWithoutNumericEntities(Reader xml,
                                                File file) {
    StringBuilder entity = new StringBuilder();

    try (Writer out = Files.newBufferedWriter(file.toPath())) {
        int c;
        while ((c = xml.read()) >= 0) {
            if (c == '&') {
                c = xml.read();
                if (c == '#') {
                    entity.setLength(0);
                    int codepoint;

                    c = xml.read();
                    if (c == 'x' || c == 'X') {
                        while ((c = xml.read()) != ';') {
                            entity.append((char) c);
                        }
                        codepoint = Integer.parseInt(entity.toString(), 16);
                    } else {
                        entity.setLength(0);
                        do {
                            entity.append((char) c);
                        } while ((c = xml.read()) != ';');
                        codepoint = Integer.parseInt(entity.toString());
                    }

                    out.write(Character.toChars(codepoint));
                } else {
                    out.write('&');
                    out.write(c);
                }
            } else {
                out.write(c);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
}

public static boolean write(File file, Document document) {

    Transformer transformer = null;
    try {
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();

        transformer.setOutputProperty("indent", "yes");
        // non-BMP characters written in characters (no numeric character reference style)
        // when you set encoding UTF-16
        transformer.setOutputProperty("encoding", "UTF-8");
        transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xalan}indent-amount", "2");

        Thread fixXmlThread;
        try (PipedWriter destination = new PipedWriter()) {
            PipedReader xmlWithNumericEntities = new PipedReader(destination);
            fixXmlThread = Thread.startVirtualThread(
                () -> writeWithoutNumericEntities(xmlWithNumericEntities, file));

            transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(destination));
        }

        fixXmlThread.join();
    } catch (TransformerException | IOException | InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         return false;
    }

    return true;
}

This does not account for comments and CDATA sections, which could contain text that would break the above code.  It can be modified to take comments and CDATA into account, though.
